# Declaring integer: Type Mismatch Error when using sumproduct with countif

Tags: vba, excel, integer, type-mismatch

Can anyone help me with the following:

```
Dim fundcount as integer

FundCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumProduct(1 / Application.CountIf(Range("B12:B28"), Range("B12:B28")))
```

I am getting a type mismatch error on this script.

The purpose of the script is to count a range of text results and return a unique value that can then be used in a loop later on in the code.

Thanks in advance

Comment: To clarify, you're trying to count the number of _unique values_ within a range? Or count the number of cells which are a _specific_ value?

Answer (score 1):

`CountIf` does not take a range as its second parameter.  It should be a value like `32` or `"Some text"`.

See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheetfunction-countif-method-excel?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: I understand that, however as it is within a sumproduct, it should work? See here: https://exceljet.net/formula/count-unique-values-in-a-range-with-countif

Comment: @DP1242 being nested in another function call doesn't change a function's arguments. The 2nd argument cannot be a range; whether it's nested in a SUMPRODUCT or a WHATHAVEYA is completely irrelevant.

Comment: It appears that there is a significant difference between the `COUNTIF` formula and the `CountIf` method available on the `WorksheetFunction` object, leading to this limitation.  This has been answered, it looks like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676068/count-unique-values-in-excel

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using a UDF to get around this problem.

Answer (score 0):

CountIf will count the number of cells that match your criteria. It does not change because you've placed it in SumProduct formula.

If you are counting everything, try using Count instead of CountIf

Comment: If I input this formula within a worksheet cell directly however it will return the desired result....

Comment: @DP1242 Excel can handle array calculations - VBA cannot.

Comment: @DP1242 are you trying to count all cells in that range or only specific ones?